# YouTube asked me to link my YouTube channel to Google+; how do I undo it?

Tags: youtube, google-plus

YouTube just asked me to link my YouTube channel to a Google+ page, and once I agreed, I noticed that my watch history, liked videos are all gone.

I remember seeing an option to Undo this, where/how can I do this from?

Answer (score 1):

You can disconnect the Google+ page; the restriction is that you must do this within 14 days of linking.

To do this, [follow these steps](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657858?hl=en%27)

- Sign in with the page owner's Google Account and switch into the channel in YouTube.
- Go to [YouTube account settings](http://youtube.com/account)
- Click on the link to disconnect Google+